# Android tvdpi layout

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-7

This is driving me crazy !
I want the Nexus 7 and the other normal 7" tablets to use different layouts.
I tried multiple combinations but they always end up using the same layout.

Ex:

- layout-sw600dp-tvdpi
- layout-sw600dp-mdpi

With this example , both the 1024x600 tablet and the Nexus 7 end up using the tvdpi layout.
That's strange since the 1024x600 is not a tvdpi.

So how can I have separate layouts ?

Comment: Check out my answer here, about the weird "tvdpi" thing, maybe it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31354564/2019384

Answer (score 1):

I think that 1024x600 is hdpi. And if you replace mdpi with hdpi everything will be fine.
Android can choose layout-sw600dp-tvdpi instead of layout-sw600dp-mdpi, because tvdpi is more similar with hdpi.

Comment: I ended up using the same layout for both the nexus 7 and the 1024x600 tablets and use a dimensions xml file to reorganize things according to the screen size. Working well and I don't have to manage 2 different layouts.