# Why is my app not available for specific devices

Tags: android, google-play

The **why** is the main point of my question.

I know there's a filtering system using the requirements and features specified in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and that furthermore one can manually exclude devices.

But, **is there a way to find out, which specific requirements or features lead to the exclusion?**

In the `Google Developer Console` the devices just show up as "unsupported", but without any further information about **why** they are not supported. I'm sure they were rejected for a good reason. But how to find out for what reason? I would really prefer a more generic method, than comparing each requirement and feature with the manifest file.

[image: Google Developer Console]
*This is just an example screen shot, and does not indicate the devices I wish to find out why they're excluded.*

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because varieties of device hardware specification and software specification. For example there are many kind of screen size, density, resolution etc. Internal memory, RAM, CPU and soon which is have range from low specification to high specification. For software there are software version and preinstalled library (some device replace small part of default Google Android library with third party library). I hope you can understand what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but my question was, how can I find out what exactly leads to the "exclusion". For sure, I can check any hardware and software detail, and compare them to the specifications in the manifest file, but that cannot be the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is (at least at the moment) **no general method** to find out, what exactly leads to an exclusion. So, one has to try and error to find it out.

Thanks go to [Neal Ahluvalia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4736841/neal-ahluvalia) for driving me in the right direction.

---

However, in my case the problem was that the devices did not match the `android:screenDensity` in `<compatible-screens>`. Which is really weird as I had everything from `mdpi` up to `640` in there, for any `android:screenSize` from `normal` to `xlarge`.

According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) it looks like going from `mdpi` up to `xxxhdpi` (= `640`) leaves no gap between the ranges covered by those.
But there is (at least) definitely one gap, where `tvdpi` comes in (which btw is considered for TV screens.. 0_o).

Somehow those devices fall under this weird `tvdpi` not mentioned on that page, until you scroll all the way down to a table where you can find it.
That's not yet the end of the story.. you'll have to add this `tvdpi` not by its name, but rather by its dpi value =>  `android:screenDensity="213"`, like you also have to do for dpi values larger than `xhdpi`.

At this point there's a big "WTF" in my head. Thanks Google for creating the worst understandable system one can imagine of.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some methods in your app that don't meet up minimum requirements(Hardware or Software, ex. RAM,Processor, API Level or something else) with those devices.

In my case i was using some third party libraries that didn't support some devices(on API Level Basis).

Comment: Ok, I'm sure, that's somehow the case. I do expect google to exclude them for some reason.. The question is, how to find out, for what reason they were excluded, in a more generic way than just comparing any hardware or software detail to the specifications in the manifest file.

Comment: There is no direct way to find out that leads exactly to your question. But you may try several different things,
make apk with lower api level, than check if some devices are supported,remove some methods that require higher api level or consume more RAM.